# Migrating a classic ASP's SQL Server database from a server 2003 to a 2008r2 server

Tags: asp-classic

I have a situation where a classic ASP's SQL Server database has been moved from a server 2003 to a 2008r2. The classic asp application stills resides on a server 2003.

Now because I have never done a migrating the only thing I thought I needed to change is the SQL Server named IP address in the application's IIS deployed ini file. Currently I am using anonymous authentication and the default application pool. The application render's to the browser fine. The problem is the application is not pulling any data for the database.

It seems that I have missed something in the configuration process. Has someone done this type of migration and if so provide me a list of thing that they have done to configure the application correct and other settings for the migration?

Thanks,

Steve Holdorf

Comment: Be sure you can conect from the 2003 server to the 2008 one and you create a user in the new server with same login/credentials/permissions

Answer (score 0):

This is not an asp but a database authentication.

It sounds like you used Windows authentication to connect from asp to the old server. Windows authentication means that asp uses IIS user identity to connect to the database and in your ini-file (or asp files) you do not provide any user/password to connect to sql.

If you want to keep this type of authentication for the new database, then you would need to configure user on the new Sql Server. Look at the old server, you should find the user named similar to `domainName\WebServerMachineName$`. You would need to create the same user on the new Sql Server and grant the same rights as on the old database. Read more https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx

If this is not an issue, then you should find what is the error message when application is not pulling any data for the database.